# Is annihilator of a subspace actually the space of inner products on orthogonal vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I am reading the book *Linear Algebra Done Right* by Sheldon Axler and learning about inner products. There's presented (6.42) *Riesz Representation Theorem* which essentially shows that there's an isomorphism between $V^*$ (the dual space) and inner products on some vector $<*,v>$ (where $v \in V$).

Now see, it's known that $(Col\ A)^\perp = Row\ A^T$ ($A$ - some square matrix). And it's also known that $Null\ T' = (Range\ T)^0$ (the second is the annihilator of the range of the operator $T$). On the other hand, $T'$ has as matrix the transposed matrix of the operator $T$, that is $Row\ A^T = Null\ T'$

It is not mentioned anywhere in the book but it appears that $(Range\ T)^0$ is not just the set of all linear forms such that they equal to 0 for any vector from $Range\ T$ but they are all inner products constructed from the vectors orthogonal to $Range\ T$.

Could you please confirm my understanding on this? Thank you!

Comment: What exactly does $T'$ denote? And what is meant by the exponent $0$ in $(\mathrm{Range} T)^0$?

Comment: @Math1000 $T'$ is the dual map of some linear operator $T$ (also denoted as $T^*$). By definition $T'(\phi) = \phi \circ T$ where $\phi \in L(V,F)$ (i.e. some linear form on the vector space $V$). The $0$ exponent is the annihilator, by definition it is $U^0 = \{\phi \in L(V,F):\ \phi(u)=0\ \forall u \in U\}$ where $U$ is a subspace of $V$.

Comment: It’s not always the case that the matrix of $T'$ is the transpose of the matrix of $T$: they need to be expressed relative to dual bases of the two spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I managed to prove it to be true and it adds a rather beautiful symmetry to the theory.

Formally, my statement: Let's $\ T \in L(V)$ and $T'$ its dual map, let's also $U = \{\phi \in L(V,F):\ \phi = \langle\cdot,u\rangle\ \forall u \in (Range\ T)^\perp\}$, then $Null\ T' = (Range\ T)^0 = U$.

The first part, $Null\ T' = (Range\ T)^0$, is proved in Axler's book (3.109). Then we proceed as follows: let's $u \in (Range\ T)^\perp$ then $\phi = \langle\cdot,u\rangle$ is equal $0$ for every vector in $Range\ T$, therefore $\phi \in (Range\ T)^0$. Hence $U \subset(Range\ T)^0$. On the other hand, if $\psi \in (Range\ T)^0$, then it equals $0$ for every vector from $Range\ T$ by definition. Then, by the *Riesz Representation Theorem* there exists and only one $u\in V$ such that $\psi = \langle\cdot,u\rangle$. But then this $u$ is orthogonal to every vector from $Range \ T$. Thus $(Range\ T)^0 \subset U$. Which concludes the proof.

Analogous thing can be proven for $Range\ T' = \{\phi \in L(V,F):\ \phi = \langle\cdot,v\rangle\ \forall v \in (Null\ T)^\perp\} = (Null\ T')^0$.

That all gives a really beautiful relation between abstract theory of dual spaces and the matrix theory, where for the latter another thing is usually taught: for any matrix $A$ it's true that $(Col\ A)^\perp = Null\ A^T$ and $(Col\ A^T)^\perp = Null\ A$.

Comment: Wow, the key part of my proof has already been asked in another questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700098/is-my-understanding-of-an-annihilator-correct